# change title of create new customer account

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account, page-title, title

I need to change the title of my registration form. ex. apply for customer account
[image]

How can I change the title?

Comment: Specify your magento version

Comment: i am using magento2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module

In custom module create a layout file name with `customer_account_create.xml` at

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml**

add below code to this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

            <!-- and for the page title: -->
            <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
               <action method="setPageTitle">
                  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Page Title</argument>
               </action>
            </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Flush cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```